# upgraded react-native now xcode 14 build Multiple commands produce '/ios/build/GeneratedInfoPlistDotEnv.h'

Tags: ios, reactjs, xcode, react-native

I am new to react-native and it's been years for xcode development.

I've upgraded a project from RN 0.61.5 (previously working fine in xcode 14) to 0.72.4

I've updated a bunch of dependencies (haven't yet resolved the code debt for these) but I am trying to just run the build in xcode and am now seeing
Multiple commands produce 'ios/build/GeneratedInfoPlistDotEnv.h'

xcode shows that it is both:

- project -> build phases -> Bundle React Native code and images
- pods -> react-native-config -> build phases -> [CP-User] Config codegen

I can't find anything that says to remove one outputting GeneratedInfoPlistDotEnv.h or anything.

We use react-native-config to build using multiple .envs.

Please let me know if I've missed a step or relevant documentation.

:edit:
I have tried legacy build, removing one of the outputs. I haven’t cleared derived data yet, there’s maybe one or two other things I can try from another Multiple outputs question I found.